# Coding a embed message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was going through the discord.js guide and found this code on embedding my message
code below

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // If the message is "how to embed"
    if (message.content === 'how to embed') {
      // We can create embeds using the MessageEmbed constructor
      // Read more about all that you can do with the constructor
      // over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageEmbed
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('A slick little embed')
        .setColor(0xff0000)      
        .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
  });
```

However, I get the following error message when I run the command
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
^

```
ReferenceError: MessageEmbed is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\index.js:29:21)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Can you help me out on how to proceed further?

Comment: I assume you have `const Discord = require("discord.js");` at the start of the script? You can either add `const MessageEmbed = Discord.MessageEmbed;` below that or use `Discord.MessageEmbed` in your script.

Comment: Doesn't work still I get a error message again

Comment: Chris' code should work if you add round brackets to `Discord.MessageEmbed()`.

Comment: Still the same error message

Comment: Thank you for helping figured out the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer myself you just need to add this to your code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
```

Then you can continue with the code

```
client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "how to embed"
  if (message.content === 'how to embed') {
    // We can create embeds using the MessageEmbed constructor
    // Read more about all that you can do with the constructor
    // over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageEmbed
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      // Set the title of the field
      .setTitle('A slick little embed')
      // Set the color of the embed
      .setColor(0xff0000)
      // Set the main content of the embed
      .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
    // Send the embed to the same channel as the message
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

Worked for me hopefully works for you too